# Did Marilyn Monroe say that she could stop giving oral sex after signing her first contract?

Tags: quotes, movies

This my first question here. I hope it is appropriate for this site.

I recently saw [here](http://www.gnomikologikon.gr/authquotes.php?auth=432) (I am translating from Greek) that Marilyn Monroe after signing her first contract said something like

> "Finally I can stop [*oral sex*]"

Did Marilyn Monroe say this quote?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

According to [The Genius and the Goddess: Arthur Miller and Marilyn Monroe](https://books.google.com/books?id=SUvr7QceBzYC&printsec=frontcover&dq=The%20Genius%20and%20the%20Goddess&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjSlOvDtqDPAhXC1IMKHQ7KA6cQ6AEIKTAC#v=onepage&q=sucked&f=false) at page 29:

> After signing her first long-term contract with Fox, she triumphantly declared "I have sucked my last c***" [endnote 3]

Where endnote 3 is:

> Peter Bogdanovich,"Marilyn Monroe", *Who the Hell's In It: Portraits and Conversations* (New York, 2004), p. 48; James Bacon, *Hollywood is a Four Letter Town* (Chicago, 1976), p. 134; Summers, *Goddess*, p93.

Comment: Do you know the source of the quote?

Comment: @rougon see here: http://therumpus.net/2010/08/59177/ "Relying heavily on the account of Elia Kazan, who was friends with Miller and bedded Monroe before he did, Meyers classifies Monroe as “a decent-hearted kid who Hollywood had brought down, legs parted.” In order for Monroe to get jobs, he tells us, she would frequently sexually service the studio heads. When she signs her first contract with Fox, he quotes Monroe as saying, “I have sucked my last .." "

Comment: So it's just Kazan's recollections? It's a reputable press, but that seems inconclusive.

Comment: An account from someone who intimately knew her?  What would you consider to be conclusive, from the 1950s, that is realistically obtainable?

Comment: Memory is notoriously faulty. Some corroboration would be helpful.  More details would be helpful.  Did he recall that at the time or thirty years later?  Was it in a published forum or in conversation?  Also, Kazan and Miller (the book cited is about their relationship) were deeply opposed at that time bc Kazan openly named names to HUAC and Miller famously did not. That certainly gives a motive to be less than precise in one's recollection. I'm not saying it isn't true or even likely, but I don't think that's sufficient evidence alone to establish the claim.

Comment: @rougon The quote is mentioned in this 1992 article: http://www.independent.co.uk/arts-entertainment/books-some-like-it-not-marilyn-monroe-died-30-years-ago-yet-she-is-still-an-adored-icon-for-pop-1537735.html It's not something she said publicly, so we'll never really know.

Comment: Thanks for that -- I agree re never know. I was just curious to find the chain of sources on the quote.

Comment: Is it not beyond possibility this was meant euphemistically? Today, anyone reaching some level in the corporate ladder might say "I'll never have to kiss anyone's ass again" I said that the day I retired, even though I never did that literally.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer the book says by name who she sucked

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer: The question was what she said, not necessarily did (though there's a high probability that that's also true)

Comment: @rougon I updated the answer to give the 3 references from endnote 3 of chapter 3.